# C# parsing existing timestamp from db?

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse an existing timestamp from my database to a DateTime but it isn't going to well. As far as I know the following is a valid timestamp.

```
2017-03-27 02:23:37
```

What have I tried?

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row["last_used"])
```

And this

```
DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(row["last_used"]))
```

Both throw errors about it not being a valid DateTime?

How I save them:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Since the following statement works fine: DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")); I guess the issue is related to the value which comes from the database. Can't  row["last_used"] return null?

Comment: Why do you save dates as strings?

Comment: Do you store Date as a string in database?

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom pattern to format DateTime for saving, you may use the same pattern for parsing it back from string to DateTime:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("row["last_used"]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I would suggest you to use ISO standard formatting `date.ToString("o")` which will produce string like `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z`, then you may parse it without problems using `DateTime.Parse(dateStr)`

Comment: .Parse didn't work, and .ParseExact requires 3 parameters. an IFormatProvider parameter.

Comment: Try to use `CurrentCulture.InvariantCulture` as `IFormatProvider`

Comment: Thank you that worked, although I am now getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: It works with me: `var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-03-27 02:23:37", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`